# I have a button on my page which utilizes a bit of Javascript code to tweet something out but it doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, twitter

Link to the pen to demonstrate - http://codepen.io/illpill/pen/VbeVEq

```
function tweet(message, author) {
  window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=thequotemachine&text=' + encodeURIComponent('"' + message + '" ' + author + " via"));
}


$('button.tweet').click(function() {
  var currQuote = $('#quote').text();
  var currAuthor = $('#author').text();
  var truncatedString = truncateString(currQuote, currAuthor)
  tweet(truncatedString, currAuthor);
});
```

On desktop it works perfectly.. Pulls the quote and puts it into a tweet but on my iPhone when I press the button, nothing happens. Any ideas why this might happen?

The truncateString function:

```
function truncateString(str, auth) {
    var shorterStr = [];
    var charCount = 0;
    strSplit = str.split(" ");

    if (str.length > (113 - auth.length)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++) {
            if (charCount < (113 - auth.length)) {
                charCount += strSplit[i].length + 1;
                shorterStr.push(strSplit[i]);
            }
        }
        shorterStr.pop();
        return (shorterStr.join(" ") + "...");
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should be posted here using Stackoverflow snippet instead of codepen.

Comment: What's your phone browser version ? Check for updates ? I'm not able to reproduce your issue using Chrome Debug Tool which emulate iPhone website naviguation. Can you post your `truncateString` function ?

Comment: I'm using the newest update for Chrome on my iPhone

Comment: This is the working version I have online. You can try testing it on mobile - http://paulmatheson.net/webdev/the-quote-machine/index.html

Comment: Did you try to replace `.text()` by `.html()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a touch event.

```
$('button.tweet').on("click touchstart",function() {
```